# Advice not getting called in Spring-AOP

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have declared the following Aspect which advices a dao call, I'm trying to run @Before advice but its not working.

Here goes the aspect.

```
package com.hedgebenefits.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
@Aspect
public class AccessControlAspect {
    @Before("within(com.hedgebenefits.daos..*) && execution(public * *(..))")
    public void daoCall() {
        System.out.println("Before advice invoked for DAO method called ");
    }
}
```

My application-context.xml has the following tag

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

My Dao class is as follows:

```
package com.hedgebenefits.daos.impl;

import com.hedgebenefits.daos.AdminDao;
import com.hedgebenefits.domain.Admin;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class AdminDaoImpl implements AdminDao{
    @Override
    public void save(Admin admin) {
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint but I can see that its not active, I'm definitely doing some silly mistake here but can't figure out. Pl. advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your aspect needs to be a part of your application context.

1. If you are using `component-scan`, either add `@Component` to your `AccessControllerAspect`, or setup the `component-scan` filters to include `@Aspect` annotations.  To setup the filters, take a look at [section 3.10.3 of the Spring documentation (Using filters to customize scanning)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config).
2. If you are using xml configuration, add a bean for `AccessControllerAspect`.

The act of adding `aop:aspectj-autoproxy` is not enough.  This tells beans that are **already a part of your application context** how to do the aspecting, it does not automatically include them.